# What happens in epoch of a blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, session, epoch, time

I have been working on a substrate blockchain. I want to know about the events and process happening in each ***epoch*** of blockchain and what are the concepts behind the ***epoch***?

Comment: This really depends on the chain. Which chain are you asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An epoch is generally used with babe consensus algorithm, I suggest you learn more about how the algorithm works [here](https://polkadot.network/blog/polkadot-consensus-part-3-babe/)

> BABE execution happens in sequential non-overlapping phases known as epochs. Each epoch is divided into a predefined number of slots. All slots in each epoch are sequentially indexed starting from 0 (slot number). At the beginning of each epoch, the BABE node needs to run the Block-Production-Lottery algorithm to find out in which slots it should produce a block and gossip to the other block producers.

If we don't have epochs we would have just infinite number of steps but that would make the VRF computation impractical and inefficient. Epochs provide a way to update the randomness and the validator set periodically in a more random and fair way.

> To make a long story short, a lot of applications depend on random
> number generation, but it can be difficult to find randomness that
> everyone agrees is random (and not gamed such that the generator
> benefits) when all on-chain operations must be deterministic and
> verifiable.

Comment: Could you lend some details about the block-production-lottery algorithm?

Comment: @Purple_Turtle thats the vrf part, read this part https://polkadot.network/blog/polkadot-consensus-part-3-babe#primary-slot-leaders